# Getting "The application [APPLICATION NAME] ( [APPLICATION ADDRESS] ) has stopped working unexpectedly. Please try again"

Tags: motorola-droid, force-close

I have a Motorola Razor running on Android Version 2.2.2.

Over the past 3 days, whenever I turn on the phone, the following message appears on the screen:

> "The application [APPLICATION NAME] ( [APPLICATION ADDRESS] ) has stopped working unexpectedly. Please try again". Application name: Email, Messaging, Google Services, Market, The Weather Chanel, etc.

After force closing the initial message, up to 10 similar messages appear until the home screen finally opens.

If I click on the Google browser or any app, the error message(s) again appears and as a result I cannot access the Internet or run any apps.

Does anyone out there know how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a database got corrupted, but perhaps it's just cache.  Try clearing your cache via ClockworkMod Recovery if you have it or an app like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tw.nicky.CleanCache) if you don't.  Running "Fix permissions" in CWM or ROM Manager might also help if you're rooted.

If that doesn't work take a look at your logcat and see if there are any errors that are more clear about what the problem is.  Otherwise I'd probably opt for a factory reset; unfortunately, I don't think it would be easy to track down what exactly was corrupted without more info.